# cdc_acm : failed to set dtr/rts - can not communicate with usb cdc device

Tags: linux, usb, pic, microchip, cdc

I was trying to enumerate usb cdc device using pic24fj128gb206.
Device seems to be enumerated properly.

But when I connect my device to Linux PC, I am getting the below warning message from kernel.

```
cdc_acm 1-8.1.6.7:1.0: failed to set dtr/rts
```

And this message will repeat when I try to connect using screen.

```
screen /dev/ttyACM9 115200
```

And I am not able to communicate with my device from PC [ Ubuntu, 14.04 ]

When analysing the data using wireshark, it looks like USB communication is fine until, host issues URB_CONTROL_out and the device responds with 
URB status as `Broken Pipe (-EPIPE ) (-32)`
[image]

Can any one help me with how to debug this issue or any methods to debug further ?

Comment: Is the USB device code implemented by you? do you have its code?